# Do sustained spells need constant line-of-sight, or just for the casting?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, spells

When I cast Stealth or Invisibility on a teammate, do I need to keep him in sight (following him everywhere) to maintain the spell, or is LOS required only for the initial casting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Shadowrun FAQ](http://www.shadowrun4.com/game-resources/frequently-asked-questions/):

> **Do you need to maintain line of sight (or touch, with Touch range
>   spells) to sustain a spell? What about Permanent spells?**
>
> A spell requires a magical link (touch, sight, material link, symbolic
>   link, etc.) to cast. There is, however, no requirement for the
>   magician to maintain touch or line-of-sight while maintaining the
>   spell, as the link between caster and spell is already in effect. By
>   the same principle, you do not need to maintain touch or line of sight
>   when casting a Permanent spell; the spell must simply be maintained
>   until the spell’s effects become permanent.

One of the exceptions is when moving around an area-effect spell, cf Core rules:

> If an area-effect spell is sustained, the affected area may be moved
>   with a Complex action, as long as it remains within line of sight.

Comment: The wording on area-effect implies that it's only moving it to the new destination that requires line-of-sight to be maintained, _not_ that the caster must keep the (current) destination in sight.  Is that correct?

Comment: In the same line of though as +Clockwork-Muse, What happens if you are already sustaining an area-effect spell and new targets enter it, but you don't see them?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes, only when moving it around, I will make the wording clearer

Comment: @Felipe As far as I understand it, they would be affected as long as it's an Indirect spell

Comment: Does this apply to sr5 as well?